# Can't see Apple_HFS partition after using Minitool Partition Wizard

Tags: bootcamp, startup, partition, install

I tried to reduce my partition size using [Minitool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com) on my BOOTCAMP partition (I didn't touch Apple_HFS partition) now I can't see my Apple_HFS partition in Disk Utility.

However this partition works under bootcamp.

I think boot manager is broken. But I am not sure how can I repair while I can't see the partition.

Edit: as requested I've executed the following commands

```
readmbr  -t
readgpt  -t
```

results are

```
Selected \\.\PhysicalDrive0 to read from.
Disk ID is 028A47A7.
Sector size is 512 bytes.
Drive contains 240,057,409,536 bytes (240 GB).

Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 29185/255/63 [468862128 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -  468862127] <Unknown ID>
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

and

```
Selected \\.\PhysicalDrive0 to read from.
Sector size is 512 bytes.
Drive contains 468,862,128 sectors.
Drive contains 240,057,409,536 bytes (240 GB).

       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         MBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640   211070944      2  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
   211480584      262144
   211742728   153600000      3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   365342728        2040
   365344768   100409344      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
   465754112         752
   465754864     1269536      5  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   467024400     1837688      6  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
   468862088           7
   468862095          32         Sec GPT table
   468862127           1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: Golden rule - never touch the partitioning from within Windows. It simply doesn't understand how it's being fooled into believing it's in charge.

Comment: It is kinda too late for your golden rule ahah

Comment: So you can still boot to OS X?

Comment: No I can boot windows and os x partition files are works properly under windows however it doesn't boot

Comment: @Rodrane: How large is the Boot Camp volume and how large is the OS X volume? Also, do you have any other volumes visible on your computer. Also, what is the year/model of your Mac.

Comment: @DavidAnderson bootcamp is 70gb now and os x is 100 gb but I reduced I created third partition and it is 45gb.

macbook pro 2013 with 240 gb ssd(I bought it lately)

Answer (score 2):

The results you posted from the `readgpt` command leads me the following conclusions about your drive's partitions. The six partitions are listed in the order found on the drive.

1. ~200 MB EFI partition (Usually hidden from the user)
2. ~100 GB Windows partition
3. ~75 GB OS X partition
4. ~50 GB Windows partition
5. ~650 MB OS X recovery partition (This is exactly the correct size)
6. ~900 MB Windows partition

This is anything like what one would expect to see.

### How to Fix Your Problem

From our posts and comments, it would appear the GUIDs for partitions 2 and 3 have been reversed. (The GUIDs identify the partition types. See [this site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs) for specific types.) The third party tool that I use to fix these types of problems is `gdisk`. You can download the zip file `gdisk-windows-1.0.1.zip` from [this site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/files/gptfdisk/1.0.1/gdisk-binaries/).

Below are a the entries to `gdisk32.exe` that I made on a simulation of your disk. You should copy these entries.

```
C:\Users\david\Desktop>gdisk32 \\.\PhysicalDrive0
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): t
Partition number (1-6): 2
Current type is 'Microsoft basic data'
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 700): af00
Changed type of partition to 'Apple HFS/HFS+'

Command (? for help): t
Partition number (1-6): 3
Current type is 'Apple HFS/HFS+'
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 700): 0700
Changed type of partition to 'Microsoft basic data'

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to \\.\PhysicalDrive0.
Disk synchronization succeeded! The computer should now use the new
partition table.
The operation has completed successfully.

C:\Users\david\Desktop>
```

Your Apple_HFS partition should now appear in the Disk Utility.

> Note: For other readers, the commands used to dump the partition tables came from [this site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/readgpt/files/readgpt/1.1.0/Windows/x86/). The commands have to be executed in an "Administrator: Command Prompt" window.

To open the Command Prompt window as an Administrator using Windows 10, right click on the Start Menu icon and select "Command Prompt (Admin)". See the image below.

[image: 20]

Comment: @Rodrane: I updated my answer. Sorry that my previous post disappeared. Sometimes that just happens.

Comment: wow wow wow you are absolutely life saver!